# Why does my Spaceship not appear?

Tags: java, image, file, io, applet

This is a very simple problem to some people I'm assuming and I just can't see it. (I'm very amateur at Java).

This is some test code I wrote to try and troubleshoot why it's not working in my other project. For some reason my rocketshipStationary.png just won't show up when I load the Java Applet.

**This is my code:**

```
public class Test extends Applet {

    public Image offScreen;
    public Graphics d;
    public BufferedImage rocketship;



    public void init() {
        setSize(854, 480);
        offScreen = createImage(854,480);
        d = offScreen.getGraphics();

        try {
            rocketship = ImageIO.read(new File("rocketshipStationary.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        d.clearRect(0, 0, 854, 480);
        d.drawImage(rocketship, 100, 100, this);
        d.drawImage(offScreen, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does happen? Do you get any messages on the console? You haven't posted code for `createImage()`; is it painting over the `rocketship` in your `paint()` method?

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See this answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.  If you need to support older AWT based APIs, see [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).

Comment: Have you checked that your electronic thumb is working?

Comment: 3) `public Graphics d;` Don't store a reference to a `Graphics` object.  They are typically transitory.  In 10+ years of Java development, I have yet to see a reason for doing so.  4) `setSize(854, 480);`  The size of an applet is set in the HTML, the applet code should not try to adjust that.

Comment: I doubt reading the file works. But even if it did.. In paint, you never paint anything to g, you only paint to your own member variable d (from offscreen)..

Answer (score 2):

You should be getting a nice big stack trace that describes what happens.  The bottom line is that 'applets and files do not play well together'.

Instead, either establish an `URL` to the image and use that for `ImageIO`, or alternately use the `URL` in the [`Applet.getImage(URL)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getImage%28java.net.URL%29) method.